# Css não funciona com o gulp

Tags: gulp

Galera, boa noite

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou começando com gulp agora e to no inicio de um sisteminha. O problema é que o css não funciona. Vou enviar um print do console.

Como podem ver o app.jss tá ok, mas o app.css não...
To mandando o link da aplicação no git também, pra que vocês possam dar uma olhadinha no gulpfile, abraço...

https://github.com/julioffti/trello_com_react.js

Comment: Não é que ele não funciona, ele não está sendo é achado: **erro 404**.

Comment: Boa noite, amigo

Eu estou seguindo um curso da School of Net e o caminho pro arquivo que ele coloca lá no index.html é exatamente esse. Será que tu poderia dar uma olhadinha na aplicação que deixei o link no git?? Ainda tá bem no comecinho.